# causative usage and に

Tags: grammar, causation

> 「四条がホントに恐がっていたのは呪いじゃなくておまえさんだったんじゃないかって話」
>   「―――――チ、一撃だけじゃ足りなかったか。
>   こう、蒼香みたいにそのままカカト落とし**に連携させて**息の根止めてやれば良かった」

She kicked a girl down to the ground and the dat after that she is talking about what happened to her friend.

Why is the causative used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Causative form can be used without explicit "causee" as long as it can be inferred from the context. In this sentence, the implicit "causee" is the first attack (一撃目).

> (一撃目を)カカト落としに連携させる
>   to make it (=the first attack) chain to an axe kick

I used *chain* because this kind of 連携 sounds like fighting gamer's jargon to me.